# Wordpress plugins only loading after page refresh

Tags: wordpress, caching, plugins

One of the websites I am working on is running the last version of Wordpress and a Qode Theme from themeforest.

I hired a Fiver website speed optimization specialist however, after he was done, certain parts of the site would not load properly anymore.
Example 1: https://www.sweetsmilingsoul.com/book-a-discovery-call/ - the Calendly plugin only loads when refreshing the site
Example 2: https://www.sweetsmilingsoul.com/ the instagram plugin (FeedThemSocial) does not load with every page visit.

I am guessing it is a caching plugin. I have uninstalled all the caching plugins the Fiver guy installed but the problem still persists.

Answer (score -1):

Both of the links work fine and the plugins are loading right away. Clear your browser cache and if you have Cloudflare enabled clear the cache from there.You could also ask him what he/she has done, check if something is cached through .htacces or just restore your website to a backup

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have cleared cache and especially the FeedThemSocial Plugin does not always load.